# Created an index for a table, adding just one more column, and SQL still suggests a new index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, index-tuning

I got a recommendation for SQL Server for this query:

`SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE ( field2 < getdate() - 2557)`

Obviously the recomendation was

`CREATE INDEX idx_name on TABLE (field2) INCLUDE (field1)`

But there was an index with only one column, and the same include that I needed, so I created an index with `field2` and the `fieldx` from the other index, with the same include `field1` because I will drop the old one and stick only with the new one with 2 fields.

when I ran the query again, why is it suggesting me to create again the index with only `CREATE INDEX idx_name on TABLE (field2) INCLUDE (field1)`.

the index has 2 columns and one include. shouldn't the query be able to do a seek on the table?

For now, it's really really faster, but it's still doing a SCAN.

I've never seen this behaviour. I usually add columns on indexes that looks like the ones suggested for SQL Server and I can get a seek everytime.

table has 700k rows.

Comment: which is the leading column in your "2 column" index?

Comment: also, an index scan is not a bad thing, that's just SQL Server picking the most efficient method of accessing the required data.  Check the Actual Execution Plan for details about the type of scan, and how many rows were scanned in the index.

Comment: [Limitations of the Missing Indexes Feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms345485(v=sql.105)). There are several bullet points here that might help you understand why this is happening